# Edit series by dragged mouse event Teechart in Java

Tags: java, swing, series, teechart

I'm trying to move the curve of the graph by dragging the mouse,

> is this possible?

Here's a visual example of what I'm attempting to do:

[image]

I'm using the Teechart library in java, to draw the series I use a Jpanel (Swing).

> Is there a function that allows me to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Teechart. Maybe it will handle mouse input. If not, add a `MouseMotionListener` to the component that's displaying the graph, and implement the `mouseDragged` method. The `MouseEvent` parameter has methods to tell you where the event occurred. Use that to decide whether to update the graph, and by how much, and call the appropriate Teechart methods. You might also want to add a `MouseListener` and implement `mousePressed` and `mouseReleased`. The sequence of events should be Pressed, Dragged, possibly more drags, Released.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I've tested it, but I need to see that while dragging the mouse curve also moves, a good example can be a powerpoint curve when you move curve lines like shown above.

Comment: If you update the chart every time there's a drag event, you should see the mouse and the curve move together.